# Disabling Mathematica's automatic sort of output

Tags: output-formatting, sorting

I used Mathematica to greatly simplify an algebraic expression. I now want to copy it into some notes, but it by defaults things in a very non-intuitive manner. I have a sorting function that will sort the expression properly, but the output still reverts to Mathematica's default sorting algorithm.

As an example, let's say I want it to output: f[b] f[a].
The sorting function

```
In[1]:= sorted = Sort[Level[f[b] f[a], 1], OrderedQ[{(#2)[[1]], (#1)[[1]]}] &]

Out[1]= {f[b], f[a]}
```

properly returns a sorted list. But when I then apply the Times function to bring it back to an algebraic expression, it goes back to the default way of sorting:

```
In[2]:= Apply[Times, sorted]

Out[2]= f[a] f[b]
```

Is there a trick for formatting the output of an expression to match the ordering I would like? Preferably something I can can both view directly in Mathematica as well as copy to LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Times` has the [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Orderless.html) attribute so this sorting cannot be prevented if you also want to do calculations with the expression.  However, if you only need to *display* it once, then you can do something like this:

Suppose you already have

```
times[f[b], f[a]]
```

sorted as you like.  The just wrap it in `HoldForm` and replace `times` with `Times`.

```
HoldForm[
  times[f[b], f[a]]
] /. times -> Times
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Instead of `times` you can of course just use `List`, but once you need to deal with more than a single type of operation (e.g. both multiplication and addition), it is convenient to use distinguishable heads.